# 2 RDD that share keys but with different value How do I replace keys of RDD2 by corresponding RDD1 value

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have two RDD that share keys but with different value like

rdd1=(key,value1)

rdd2=((key, key),value2)

and replace key of RDD2 to correspond RDD1 value

result = ((value1, value1),value2)

Do you think it's possible ?

Example

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(1, "ABCD"), (2,"CDFE" ), (3,"FDFD")])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(1,2),1), ((1,3), 0), ((2,3),1)])
```

as output I'd like

```
result = ([("ABCD","CDFE"),1), (("ABCD","FDFD"), 0), (("CDFE","FDFD"),1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is turn both RDDs to dataframes. The first one with columns keyA, valA the second with keyB1,keyB2 and valB

Now do a join between them. Something like this:

```
df1 = dfB.join(dfA, on dfA["keyA"] == dfB["keyB1]).withColumnRenamed("valA", "firstKey")
df2 = df1.join(dfA, on dfA["keyA"] == df1["keyB2]).withColumnRenamed("valA", "secondKey")
```

now your dataframe has firstKey and secondKey column for the key and valB for the value, just convert back to RDD and map.

Answer (score 0):

With RDD:

```
rdd1.join(rdd1.join(
    rdd2.keyBy(lambda x: x[0][0]
 )).values().keyBy(lambda x: x[1][0][1])).values() \
     .map(lambda x: ((x[0], x[1][0]), x[1][1][1]))
```